# Azure DevOps Release Pipelines permission

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have two projects in my Azure DevOps environment. Project H and Project HB. Project H contains the Board of Tasks and Repo for source code. Project HB contains the build and release pipelines. The build works as it shoud, as does the release pipeline.
But I get an error in the "Release" view, when looking at the Commits made for the release.

TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier '' does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.

[image]

Which permissions should I configure to get the release to be able to show the commits and Work Items related to the release?

Is it possible to report the deployment status back to boards that exists in another project?

I Tried to add Read permission to the repo and boards in "Project H" for the account "Project HB Build Service".

Comment: Hi Bere, did the answer posted on the ticket help you? If it helps, just as a remind of [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks for your kindness :-)

Answer (score 1):

### 1

We have the same problem with the Stakeholder access.
Team members can open the page in your screenshot, but stakeholder have the issue as described by you.

So, it's not about the Build Service access, but the user who opens the release status should have access to Project HB.

If the user already has access, then this might be a limitations within the classic release overview.

### 2

Two answer the second part, you should however see the **build** status, of the yaml pipeline, in the work items of project H.
The deploy status, of classic release pipelines, is a different story.
AFAIK it's only reported back to the project it is in.

Maybe publishing a deployment badge can help you:
[image: classic release integration options]

### 3

Alternatively you could migrate to YAML pipelines, since reporting back of these pipelines have more options then the classic release pipelines.